# OleDB connection string for SQL Server in a C# program

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I have seen lots of answers to connect to MS Access via OleDB but there is not good answer for SQL Server. I try to connect to a SQL Server database via OleDB provider in my C# program.

This is the connection string I am providing.

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=<servername>;Initial Catalog=<dbname>;Integrated Security=SSPI
```

But it gives me error

> ‘Keyword not support ‘Provider’’

What I want to do here is connect database via OleDB in C# program.

Comment: Could you show the line where do you build your connection and try to open it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This works as expected on my side. From the error message I strongly suspect that you are using the `SqlConnection` class instead of the `OleDbConnection` (Of course you need to use all the other classes provided by OleDb like `OleDbCommand`, `OleDbDataReader` etc...)

```
  string connStr = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=<servername>;Initial Catalog=<dbname>;Integrated Security=SSPI";
  using(OleDbConnection cnn = new OleDbConnection(connStr))
  {
     ....
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

When in doubt, use the string builder in visual studio. That way unsupported keywords can't creep into your connection strings, the following is a wonderful example on how to use it.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/suthish_nair/how-to-generate-or-find-connection-string-from-visual-studio/

Answer (score 1):

The [connection string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677227%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you're using, considering the OLE DB provider, is correct. I didn't find any error in the connection string used, if you want to connect to a SQL Server data source.

Most probably, the reason of that error should be that you're not using correctly all the classes and objects required by the OLE DB provider, like `OleDbCommand` (that is similar to a `SqlCommand` but it's different), `OleDbConnection`, `OleDbDataAdapter` and so on. In a nutshell, the reason of that error should be this:

```
string connStr = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=<servername>;Initial Catalog=<dbname>;Integrated Security=SSPI";
using(SqlConnection scn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
  {
     ....
  }
```

Indeed, using a [`SqlConnection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object, the `ConnectionString` property doesn't support the keyword `Provider` and, executing your application, you got an error about a keyword not supported.

Have a look at [this simple tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288452%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) about the use of OLE DB provider.

Answer (score 1):

The same Connection string is working fine at my end.
I am posting my sample code which is executes successfully at my end

```
public   string connStr = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=.;Initial  Catalog=<dbName>;Integrated Security=SSPI";
  public OleDbConnection con;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Test();
    }

    public void Test()
    {
        con = new OleDbConnection(connStr);
        con.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from tblApartments", con);
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        con.Close();
    }
```

Please place breakpoint and check line to line and when your breakpoint comes to con.close(); then check ds, you can see the output.

Comment: at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.get_ServerVersion()
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.get_ServerVersion() two errors while connect.

Comment: Can you please place the code (or) tell me where the error is occur while connection is opening/closing (or) place error in detail